# Why do I keep getting zero and nan for these variables?

Tags: c++, math

Here is my code, for `n` and `m`, I consistently get `0` for `n` and `nan` for `m`, and I do not know why. I have tried everything I could, but `n` always shows `0` whilst `m` is always `nan`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a, b, c, root1, root2, n, m ;
    cout << "Please input values for a, b and c to represent the variables in equation : ax^2 + bx + c" << endl; // Dont know how to raise 2 instead of using ^2
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    const float d = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
    cout << "Determinant is equal to " << d << endl;
    cout << setprecision(3); // to set number of decimal places

    n = b / 2 * a;
    m = sqrt(d) / 2 * a; 
    if (d > 0) {
        root1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a); // positive root
        root2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a); // negative root
        cout << "Determinant is greater than zero, therefore the equation has two real roots, which are " << root1 << " and " << root2 << endl;
    }
    else if (d < 0) {
        cout << "Determinant is less than zero, therefore there would be two imaginary roots: " << n << " + " << m << "i ";
        cout << "and " << n << " - " << m << "i" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this program, one line at a time, and after each line you used your debugger to show the values of all variables, what did you see?

Comment: Well, what value do you think you should get instead? And why? Try to prove to me, by talking through the code, that you should get a different value. Lay out all the steps of your reasoning. We can't tell you why you misunderstand unless we know what your thought process is.

Answer (score 4):

you have to put parenthesis.

`n = b / (2 * a);`
`m = sqrt(d) / (2 * a);`

Answer (score 3):

If the d is negative, you should first convert it to a non-negative number before feed it into sqrt(). Remember C/C++ does not equal to math language.

My quick fix:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  float a, b, c, root1, root2, n, m;
  cout << "Please input values for a, b and c to represent the variables in equation : ax^2 + bx + c " << endl; // Dont know how to raise 2 instead of using ^2
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
  const float d = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
  cout << "Determinant is equal to " << d << endl;
  cout << setprecision(3); // to set number of decimal places

  n = b / (2 * a);
  if (d > 0) {
    m = sqrt(d) / (2 * a);  
    root1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a); // positive root
    root2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a); // negative root
    cout << "Determinant is greater than zero, therefore the equation has two "
            "real roots, which are "
         << root1 << " and " << root2 << endl;
  } else if (d < 0) {
    m = sqrt(-d) / (2 * a);    
    cout << "Determinant is less than zero, therefore there would be two "
            "imaginary roots: "
         << n << " + " << m << "*i ";
    cout << "and " << n << " - " << m << "*i" << endl;
  }
}
```

A reference to sqrt() function:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make some changes to get the correct answers for all cases First, you need to include the case of zero determinant which produces two identical real roots. You will need to calculate m with `-d` in the third case, and you have to make sure to change its sign into positive sign if necessary. For more aesthetic results, you can include special cases to omit `n` if it equals `0`, and `m` if it equals `1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a, b, c, root1, root2, n, m;
    cout << "Please input values for a, b and c to represent the variables in equation : ax^2 + bx + c" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    const float d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    cout << "Determinant is equal to " << d << endl;
    cout << setprecision(3); // to set number of decimal places
    
    if (d > 0)
    {
        root1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / 2 / a;
        root2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / 2 / a;
        cout << "Determinant is greater than zero, therefore the equation has two real roots, which are " << root1 << " and " << root2 << endl;
    }
    else if (d == 0)
    {
        root1 = -b / 2 / a;
        cout << "Determinant is zero, therefore the equation has two identical real roots, which both are " << root1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        n = -b / 2 / a;
        m = sqrt(-d) / 2 / a;
        if (m < 0)
            m *= -1;
        if (n == 0)
        {
            if (m == 1)
                cout << "Determinant is less than zero, therefore there would be two imaginary roots: i and -i" << endl;
            else
                cout << "Determinant is less than zero, therefore there would be two imaginary roots: " << m << "i and -" << m << "i" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (m == 1)
                cout << "Determinant is less than zero, therefore there would be two imaginary roots: " << n << " + " << "i and " << n << " - " << "i" << endl;
            else
                cout << "Determinant is less than zero, therefore there would be two imaginary roots: " << n << " + " << m << "i and " << n << " - " << m << "i" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```